# C# newline constant error upon trying to compile

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, compilation

For some reason, when I'm trying to compile my .cs file into a .dll using the Visual Studio Command Prompt, I get a `new line constant error` upon trying to compile for some reason.

It's not liking the semicolon after `+ feet"`.

Any idea why?

Here is my code:

```
/* A simple C# class! */

public class Tree
{
    public int height = 0;

    public void Grow(int h)
    {
        height += h;
    }

    public string Message()
    {
        return "The height of tree1 is:<br/>" + tree1.height + feet";
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need another " before feet

```
public string Message()
{
    return "The height of tree1 is:<br/>" + tree1.height + "feet";
}
```

**Edit:** It is actually complaining about that the last string starting with "; is not terminated.

Comment: Hey thanks, wow, I cannot believe I forgot about that.  In other code examples I posted I had forgot about it, but nobody mentioned it, so I assumed it was ok :)

Thanks!

Comment: The syntax highlighting is of great help to spot this kind of errors.